# What is the most computationally efficient way to flatmap a List of Lists?

Tags: java

There is a problem on my server where it became a bottle neck due to a specific problem to solve resolving a `List<List<SomeObject>>` into a `List<SomeObject>`. The CPU of the server spiked above normal means.

DataStructure is:

```
Object:
List<SomeObject> childList;
```

Trying to make a `List<Object>` flatmapped to `List<SomeObject>` in the most *computationally efficient* way.
If parentList = `List<Object>`:
I Tried:

```
parentList.stream().flatMap(child -> child.getChildList().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Also tried:

```
List<Object> all = new ArrayList<>();
parentList.forEach(child -> all.addAll(child.getChildList()))
```

Any other suggestions? These seem to be similar in computation but pretty high due to copying underneath the hood.

Comment: Roughly how big are theses lists? If you create the list in the second example with a calculated initial capacity based on the other lists you might be able to save several reallocations as the list needs to resize.

Comment: What is `getChildList()`?

Comment: Maybe you should make an intermediate list, `List<List<Object>>` using `getChildList()` to see if that contains your bottleneck. You're only going to get minor improvements on the `List<List<Object>>` -> `List<Object>` the biggest being, pre-allocate the size of the destination list. You should use an actual profiler, to make sure you have found the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

This may be more efficient since it eliminates creating multiple streams via flatMap. [MapMulti](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) was introduced in Java 16.  It takes the streamed `argument` and a `consumer` which puts something on the stream, in this case each list's object.

```
List<List<Object>> lists =  new ArrayList<>(
                List.of(List.of("1", "2", "3"),
                List.of("4", "5", "6", "7"),
                List.of("8", "9")));


List<Object> list = lists.stream().mapMulti(
         (lst, consumer) -> lst.forEach(consumer))
         .toList();

System.out.print(list);
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

In java 8

```
List<Object> listOne = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> listTwo = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> listThree = new ArrayList<>(); 
...
```

`Stream.of(...)` concatenate many lists

```
List<Object> newList = Stream.of(listOne,listTwo,listThree).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In Java 16+

```
List<Object> newList=Stream.concat(Stream.concat(listOne, listTwo), listThree).toList();
```

Being an ETL (“Extract Transform and Load”) process, `Streams` processes collections of data using multiple threads of execution at each stage of processing.

Comment: `Stream.concat()` only takes two arguments. You need to do `Stream.concat(Stream.concat(listOne, listTwo), listThree)...`

Comment: also how is this answering the question?

Comment: Making use of `Streams` makes processing more efficient because multiple threads solve tasks separately.

Comment: @Armando First, multiple threads do not always make processing more efficient.  Time to set up the threads vs the time to process on a single thread may make the task less efficient.   Second, streams do not automatically operate in different threads and you didn't specify parallel in your example.   And the `JavaDoc` for `concat` says that if you have more than two streams it may be more efficient to use `Stream<T> concat = Stream.of(s1, s2, s3, s4).flatMap(s -> s);`

Comment: Why would you use Stream.of, it seems like the OP already has a List<List<Object>> which would give you a Stream<List<Object>> if you used List#stream?

Comment: @Matt Are you referring to my comment? I was just quoting the `JavaDoc` on `concat` of more than two streams vs `Stream.of` multiple streams.  That was not a direct suggestion to answer the OP's question.

Comment: @WJS no I was referring to the answer, they're using Stream.of + flatMap which is nearly identical to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Do we know more about which List implementation is used?

I would try to init the resulting list with the correct expected size.
This avoids unnecessary copying.
This assumes that the size of the lists can be retrieved fast.

```
int expectedSize = parentList.stream()
                             .mapToInt(entry -> entry.getChildList().size())
                             .sum();
List<SomeObject> result = new ArrayList<>(expectedSize);
for (var entry : parentList) {
   result.addAll(entry.getChildList());
}
```